# How can i include /main/groovy class in maven produced jar

Tags: maven

i want to produce a jar of my maven project which also to include the groovy classed which exist under the /main/groovy path.

how can i do it?

Comment: Take a look at [`gmaven`](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) plugin.

Comment: Why can't you just put the groovy jar in your application classpath?

Comment: i want to produce one jar which will include the java classes and also the groovy ones.Now, as i show, the mvn clean install creates a jar file with only the java classes

Answer (score 0):

Use the [addSources](http://groovy.github.io/GMavenPlus/addSources-mojo.html) goal of GMavenPlus, addsource goal of GMaven, or the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/).