# Groovy & maven - compile sourcesfrom src/main/groovy

Tags: java, maven, groovy, jar, pom.xml

I have been searching for few hours how to build .jar with maven.
Finnaly i got it.

But now i have to have sources in src/main/java.

How to 'include' src/main/groovy to my project?
I read solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773439/how-can-i-include-main-groovy-class-in-maven-produced-jar) but I really don't want to change my pom.xml. I had so many troubles with this.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.thornydev</groupId>
<artifactId>script</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>script</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>pl.jedro.Main</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-beta-3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried with:

```
        <sources>
            <source>${basedir}/src/main/groovy</source>
          </sources>
```

and

```
    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/groovy</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

but still nothing.

I got :

> Error: Could not find or load main class pl.jedro.Main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got solution.

I added:

```
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>groovy</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

in `<build> </build>` section.